# How to add tabs and show the name of the button in the header of the application?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

How to add submenu or tabs in the upper part in connection with the lower button and show the name of the lower button in the header of the application.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { MaterialIcons, MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import Splash from '../screens/Splash';
import NewsListScreen from '../screens/NewsListScreen';
import NewsItemScreen from '../screens/NewsItemScreen';


const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    //Splash: {screen: Splash},
    News: {
        screen: NewsListScreen
    },
    NewsItem: {
        screen: NewsItemScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'News Item'
        }
    }
});

const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: () => <MaterialIcons name="home" size={24} />
        }
    },
    News: {
        screen: StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: () => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="newspaper-variant-outline" size={24} />
        }
    }
})

export default createAppContainer(BottomTabNavigator);
```

What I want to achieve is the following:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom button `[News]` has three referential buttons in the upper part `[FEATURED], [RELEVANT], [SEARCH]` and, in addition to that, it recovers the name of the bottom button and adds it to the application header below the top buttons.

Comment: You can have an app (containing bottom tab navigator) and then a Sub App (containing top tab navigator). Each sub app will be a screen (component), hence it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED]
Your `NewsListScreen` screen, instead of just being a tab bar component, can be something like that:

```js
function NewsListScreen = (props) => (
  <View>
    <Text>News</Text>
    <TabBarComponent {...props} />
  </View>
)

function TabBarComponent = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  featured: ... ,
  relevant: ... ,
  search: ... ,
})
```

That being said, if you can, you should update your project to react navigation v5, which is I think much more user friendly.

Comment: Your example is very basic, I don't understand it :( only if I can tell you it's that I'm using the most recent libraries since I'm doing this project this year, on the same date and month.

Comment: Although the code alternative is different from the one I already have, I am using another code structure, for this I am using `import {AppLoading} from 'expo';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';`

Comment: well looking at the way you write your code, you're using react-navigation v4, not react-navigation v5... but it doesn't matter. I'll edit my answer to explain better

Comment: mi file package.json https://jsfiddle.net/5wcr4ogs/ So I'm using version 4 code, but it works then the same in v5, because I have installed the latest add-ons, friend

Answer (score 0):

**Final Output:**

[image]

**Implementation using `react-navigation v5` :**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  useNavigationState,
} from '@react-navigation/native';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

/*
Here I am using MaterialTopTabNavigator instead of StackNavigator,
which is a better choice based on UI snapshot in this case.
*/
function NewsTopTabs() {

/*
in case you want to set the title dynamically then you can use the 
useNavigationState hook but as there are just two bottom tabs so 
I am using hardcoded values.
*/

  const nav = useNavigationState((state) => state);
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.titleBar}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>News</Text>
      </View>
      <TopTab.Navigator>
        <TopTab.Screen name="Featured" component={Featured} />
        <TopTab.Screen name="Relevant" component={Relevant} />
        <TopTab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
      </TopTab.Navigator>
    </>
  );
}

function MatchesTopTabs() {

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.titleBar}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Matches</Text>
      </View>
      <TopTab.Navigator>
        <TopTab.Screen name="Featured" component={Featured} />
        <TopTab.Screen name="Relevant" component={Relevant} />
        <TopTab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
      </TopTab.Navigator>
    </>
  );
}

function MyBottomTabs({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator>
      <BottomTab.Screen name="News" component={NewsTopTabs} />
      <BottomTab.Screen name="Matches" component={MatchesTopTabs} />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}

//[FEATURED], [RELEVANT], [SEARCH]

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyBottomTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

//[FEATURED], [RELEVANT], [SEARCH]
const Featured = () => {
  const nav = useNavigationState((state) => state);
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Text>Featured</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const Relevant = () => {
  const nav = useNavigationState((state) => state);
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Text>Relevant</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const Search = () => {
  const nav = useNavigationState((state) => state);
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Text>Search</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  titleBar: {
    height: 50,
    width: Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width),
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderBottomColor: "lightgrey",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    paddingLeft: 10,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  screen:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});
```

Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/honest-tortillas)

Comment: Previously I already had the design implemented in that way https://jsfiddle.net/nb5tmhdo/, but the way I have raised my code is much more organized ... any solution using my current code structure of my question?